# propagate conditional column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create an indicator variable that will propagate to all rows with the same customer-period value pair as the indicator. Specifically, if `baz` is `yes`, I want all rows of that same customer and period email to show my indicator.

```
df
  Customer  Period Question Score
        A       1      foo     2
        A       1      bar     3
        A       1      baz   yes
        A       1      biz     1
        B       1      bar     2
        B       1      baz    no
        B       1      qux     3
        A       2      foo     5
        A       2      baz   yes
        B       2      baz   yes          
        B       2      biz     2
```

I've tried

```
df['Indicator'] = np.where(
                 (df.Question.str.contains('baz') & (df.Score == 'yes')),            
                 1, 0)
```

which returns

```
   Customer  Period Question Score  Indicator
         A       1      foo     2          0
         A       1      bar     3          0
         A       1      baz   yes          1
         A       1      biz     1          0
         B       1      bar     2          0
         B       1      baz    no          0
         B       1      qux     3          0
         A       2      foo     5          0
         A       2      baz   yes          1
         B       2      baz   yes          1
         B       2      biz     2          0
```

But this is the desired output:

```
   Customer  Period Question Score  Indicator
         A       1      foo     2          1
         A       1      bar     3          1
         A       1      baz   yes          1
         A       1      biz     1          1
         B       1      bar     2          0
         B       1      baz    no          0
         B       1      qux     3          0
         A       2      foo     5          1
         A       2      baz   yes          1
         B       2      baz   yes          1
         B       2      biz     2          1
```

I'm not sure how to go about getting what I want. Maybe groupby with ffill and another with bfill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
In [954]: df['Indicator'] = (df.assign(eq=df.Question.eq('baz') & df.Score.eq('yes'))
                               .groupby(['Customer', 'Period'])['eq']
                               .transform('any').astype(int))

In [955]: df
Out[955]:
   Customer  Period Question Score  Indicator
0         A       1      foo     2          1
1         A       1      bar     3          1
2         A       1      baz   yes          1
3         A       1      biz     1          1
4         B       1      bar     2          0
5         B       1      baz    no          0
6         B       1      qux     3          0
7         A       2      foo     5          1
8         A       2      baz   yes          1
9         B       2      baz   yes          1
10        B       2      biz     2          1
```

---

Details

```
In [956]: df.Question.eq('baz') & df.Score.eq('yes')
Out[956]:
0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10    False
dtype: bool

In [957]: df.assign(eq=df.Question.eq('baz') & df.Score.eq('yes'))
Out[957]:
   Customer  Period Question Score  Indicator     eq
0         A       1      foo     2          1  False
1         A       1      bar     3          1  False
2         A       1      baz   yes          1   True
3         A       1      biz     1          1  False
4         B       1      bar     2          0  False
5         B       1      baz    no          0  False
6         B       1      qux     3          0  False
7         A       2      foo     5          1  False
8         A       2      baz   yes          1   True
9         B       2      baz   yes          1   True
10        B       2      biz     2          1  False
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way. The idea is to use a Boolean mask with `MultiIndex`. Then use `pd.Series.isin` to compare against your filtered indices.

```
mask = (df['Question'] == 'baz') & (df['Score'] == 'yes')
idx_cols = ['Customer', 'Period']
idx = df.set_index(idx_cols).loc[mask.values].index

df['Indicator'] = pd.Series(df.set_index(idx_cols).index.values).isin(idx).astype(int)

print(df)

   Customer  Period Question Score  Indicator
0         A       1      foo     2          1
1         A       1      bar     3          1
2         A       1      baz   yes          1
3         A       1      biz     1          1
4         B       1      bar     2          0
5         B       1      baz    no          0
6         B       1      qux     3          0
7         A       2      foo     5          1
8         A       2      baz   yes          1
9         B       2      baz   yes          1
10        B       2      biz     2          1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can factorize the tuples of `Customer` and `Period`.  Then use `np.logical_or.at` to get group-wise `any`

```
i, r = pd.factorize([*zip(df.Customer, df.Period)])
a = np.zeros(len(r), dtype=np.bool8)
np.logical_or.at(a, i, df.eval('Question == "baz" and Score == "yes"'))
df.assign(Indicator=a[i].astype(np.int64))

   Customer  Period Question Score  Indicator
0         A       1      foo     2          1
1         A       1      bar     3          1
2         A       1      baz   yes          1
3         A       1      biz     1          1
4         B       1      bar     2          0
5         B       1      baz    no          0
6         B       1      qux     3          0
7         A       2      foo     5          1
8         A       2      baz   yes          1
9         B       2      baz   yes          1
10        B       2      biz     2          1
```

---

### Explanation

```
i, r = pd.factorize([*zip(df.Customer, df.Period)])
```

produces unique `(Customer, Period)` pairs in `r` where `i` is an array keeping track of which element of `r` went where in order to produce the original list of tuples

1. Original list of tuples

   ```
   [*zip(df.Customer, df.Period)]

   [('A', 1),
    ('A', 1),
    ('A', 1),
    ('A', 1),
    ('B', 1),
    ('B', 1),
    ('B', 1),
    ('A', 2),
    ('A', 2),
    ('B', 2),
    ('B', 2)]
   ```
2. After factorizing, unique tuples `r`

   ```
   r

   array([('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 2)], dtype=object)
   ```
3. And the positions `i`

   ```
   i

   array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
   ```

I can now use `i` as indices for evaluating grouped `any` in Numpy using Numpy's `at` method on `ufuncs`.  Basically, this allows me to create an array upfront whose values may change based on my `at` operation.  Then specify an array of indices (that's what `i` will be) and an array matching the size of `i` that is the second part of my operation at that index.

I end up using as my matching array

```
df.eval('Question == "baz" and Score == "yes"')

0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10    False
dtype: bool
```

Let me show this in painstaking detail

```
     Flag  GroupIndex   Group    State of a
0   False           0  (A, 1)  [0, 0, 0, 0]  # Flag is False, So do Nothing
1   False           0  (A, 1)  [0, 0, 0, 0]  # Flag is False, So do Nothing
2    True           0  (A, 1)  [1, 0, 0, 0]  # Flag is True, or_eq for Index 0
3   False           0  (A, 1)  [1, 0, 0, 0]  # Flag is False, So do Nothing
4   False           1  (B, 1)  [1, 0, 0, 0]  # Flag is False, So do Nothing
5   False           1  (B, 1)  [1, 0, 0, 0]  # Flag is False, So do Nothing
6   False           1  (B, 1)  [1, 0, 0, 0]  # Flag is False, So do Nothing
7   False           2  (A, 2)  [1, 0, 0, 0]  # Flag is False, So do Nothing
8    True           2  (A, 2)  [1, 0, 1, 0]  # Flag is True, or_eq for Index 2
9    True           3  (B, 2)  [1, 0, 1, 1]  # Flag is True, or_eq for Index 3
10  False           3  (B, 2)  [1, 0, 1, 1]  # Flag is False, So do Nothing
```

The final `State` is `[1, 0, 1, 1]` or in boolean terms `[True, False, True, True]`.  And that represents the `or` accumulation within each unique group that is housed in `a`

```
a

array([ True, False,  True,  True])
```

If I slice this with the index positions in `i` and cast as integers, I get

```
a[i].astype(np.int64)

array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Which is precisely what we were looking for.

Finally, I use `assign` to produce a copy of the dataframe with its new column.

```
df.assign(Indicator=a[i].astype(np.int64))

   Customer  Period Question Score  Indicator
0         A       1      foo     2          1
1         A       1      bar     3          1
2         A       1      baz   yes          1
3         A       1      biz     1          1
4         B       1      bar     2          0
5         B       1      baz    no          0
6         B       1      qux     3          0
7         A       2      foo     5          1
8         A       2      baz   yes          1
9         B       2      baz   yes          1
10        B       2      biz     2          1
```

---

## Why Do it This Way?!

Numpy is often faster.
Below is a slightly more optimized approach.  (basically the same)

```
i, r = pd.factorize([*zip(df.Customer, df.Period)])
a = np.zeros(len(r), dtype=np.bool8)
q = df.Question.values == 'baz'
s = df.Score.values == 'yes'
m = q & s
np.logical_or.at(a, i, m)
df.assign(Indicator=a[i].astype(np.int64))
```